# Export tabulation in Excel

Tags: stata

Consider the following toy example:

```
sysuse auto, clear

tab foreign, sum(price)

            |          Summary of Price
   Car type |        Mean   Std. Dev.       Freq.
------------+------------------------------------
   Domestic |   6,072.423   3,097.104          52
    Foreign |   6,384.682   2,621.915          22
------------+------------------------------------
      Total |   6,165.257   2,949.496          74
```

How can I save the results in an Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

Using the *community-contributed* command `esttab`, the following works for me:

```
sysuse auto, clear

egen m_total = mean(price)
egen s_total = sd(price)

scalar mtotal = m_total
scalar stotal = s_total
scalar N = _N

collapse (mean) Mean=price (sd) StdDev=price (count) Freq = price, by(foreign)
set obs 3

replace Mean = mtotal in 3
replace StdDev = stotal in 3
replace Freq = N in 3

mkmat Mean StdDev Freq, matrix(A)

esttab matrix(A) using myfilename.xls, varlabels(r1 Domestic r2 Foreign r3 Total) ///
                  title("           Summary of Price") mlabels(none)

                       Summary of Price
---------------------------------------------------
                     Mean       StdDev         Freq
---------------------------------------------------
Domestic         6072.423     3097.104           52
Foreign          6384.682     2621.915           22
Total            6165.257     2949.496           74
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @rakib hasan my answer clearly solves your problem. Please up-vote it using the upper arrow and accept it with the check-mark. This is how you reward volunteers on here for their time and ensure they will help you again in the future.